# Error using quick and nimble: "Modifications to the layout engine must not be performed from a background thread..."

Tags: ios, swift

I'm testing coordinator, but I get the following error:

> Thread 8: "Modifications to the layout engine must not be performed from a background thread after it has been accessed from the main thread."

```
final class MainCoordinatorTests: QuickSpec {
    override func spec() {
        
        var sut: MainCoordinator!
        var navigationControllerMock: UINavigationControllerMock!
        var viewControllerMock: ViewControllerMock!
        
        beforeEach {
            navigationControllerMock = UINavigationControllerMock()
            viewControllerMock = ViewControllerMock()
            sut = MainCoordinator(navigationController: navigationControllerMock,
                                  flow: .firstFlow)
            
            UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
        }
        
        describe("#start") {
            beforeEach {
                sut.start()
            }
            
            it("pushes HomeViewController") {
                expect(sut.currentViewController).to(beAKindOf(HomeViewController.self))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Could anyone help?

Comment: The error message is implying that your code is running on a background thread. Don't do that.

Comment: You need to work where you called `pushViewController` from a background thread. Possibly as a result of some network operation. Create a [main thread checker breakpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50019004/3418066) and then you can examine your call stack to identify the source of the problem.

Comment: See [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Modifications+to+the+layout+engine+must+not+be+performed+from+a+background+thread+after+it+has+been+accessed+from+the+main+thread.) for lots of discussions about the error.